# Why are the process priorities not respected?

Tags: process, priority

I was running four jobs in the background with HTCondor. It sets the priority to 10. Then I was compiling something with `make -j4` in the foreground (priority 0). However, the HTCondor jobs still got most of the CPU time, which I find a little strange.

[image: htop screenshot]

The background job does not interact with the disk at all and only little with memory, it is very CPU bound. The compilation might be a little different, but I still do not really understand why `clang` only gets less than 20% per CPU.

When I run this without anything else running, the `clang` processes get most of the cores. In the screenshot, one of them was finished, so only three showed up. But all four cores were really doing hard work:

[image]

How can I really background a task?

Comment: A highly i/o bound process is never going to compete with a cpu bound process no matter what the relative priorities.  As an interesting test try stopping the condor jobs and then running your make.  I'll bet that they still use less than 30-40% of the cpu.

Comment: I tested this, and it seems that they use near 100%.

Comment: can't comment as I have too few points, and this is definitely not an answer, just an attempt at explanation. I/O bound process will almost always get priority over cpu bound process. This is due to assumption that I/O bound are blocking but for a short duration, while the reverse is true for cpu-bound. That said - compilation is usually cpu bound as well. I did notice one thing - the condor procs were all sleeping. That could indicate they are actually I/O bound, or, more likely, interdependent and waiting on results from each other. I would assume that the scheduler, not knowing the differen

Comment: I doubt that they are sleeping because they are waiting on each other, they should be mostly independent since they are running a copy of my program each. I guess HTCondor put them to sleep since I used the machine. IT is just puzzling that they still consumed most of the CPU.

Comment: Sleeping doesn't mean something else "put them to sleep", it means the process is blocked, waiting for something, usually I/O. When that event occurs, the process will wake up and be given a temporary priority boost. If this is happening often enough, it might be the reason for the anomalous performance.